# how do i force matlab to work in pixel indices coordinates

Tags: matlab, image-processing, coordinates

I am new to programming. I am trying to make a plot on an image but realize that Matlab gives me the default spatial coordinates. However, i do wish to switch to pixel indices rather than the spatial coordinates. Please, how can i achieve this?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean? When you plot an image it gives you the pixel indices.

Comment: define _default spatial coordinates_, _pixel indices_, and shows the commands you use so far to get your coordinates.

Comment: A quick picture of what you're seeing and what you hope to see might be useful here

Comment: I have just added a picture displayed with the 'image' function which by default shows a top left corner of (0.5,0.5). I assumed this to be the default spatial coordinate because i was expecting a (0,0) for pixel coordinates

Comment: Have you tried looking at it with `axis image`?  Is the problem in the display?

Answer (score 0):

If you plot (in Matlab or elsewhere) origin is in the bottom left corner, x axis goes from left to right, y axis goes from the ground to the sky.

If you load an image in Matlab (or quite elsewhere) the program read it as a matrix in which an element is identified by its row and its column. The origin (lowest row, lowest column) is in the top left corner. The column number increase along the x axis, the row number increas from the top of the image to the bottom.

Basically you have to remember this last difference to find a point in a matrix (image) from the coordinates given in the normal plot.
If this spatial coordinates are (x_p, y_p) the point in the matrix (image) IMG is

```
IMG = imread('image.jpg');
[Height,Width] = size(IMG);
pixel_value = IMG(Height-y_p, x-p); %find a value in pixel coordinates
```

Comment: I thought this reference could complete your answer well: http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/matlab/plot_over_image_background
(when I started to play with this, this blog post has been of incredible help!)

Comment: @marcoresk: the issue isn't about finding a point in an image, but converting to another form of coordinate.

Comment: @Eskapp: thank you for the link, seems quite an interesting blog to follow.